# Problems displaying values ​with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I recently started using Spring with Thymeleaf and when making a project I had this error.I apologize if the question is stupid but I can't find the solution. I have two model classes, Team Home and TeamAway and a third class Match that has to give me statistics based on the fields of TeamHome and TeamAway.
I need to have two entities TeamHome and TeamAway to calculate the statistics of the same team separately both at home and away.
I rewrote the code like this:
I create the TeamHome and TeamAway entity (this is no problem) and then I create a Match entity that has the TeamHome and TeamAway objects as fields.

TeamAway entity

```
@Entity
public class TeamAway {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer teamAwayId;

private String nameTeamAway;
private int goalsScoredAway;
private int goalsConcededAway;
private int gamesPlayedAway;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teamAway", cascade =  CascadeType.ALL)
private List<MatchAnalyses> matchAnalysesAway;

public TeamAway() {
}
```

TeamHome entity

```
@Entity
public class TeamHome{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer teamHomeId;

private String nameTeamHome;
private int goalsScoredHome;
private int goalsConcededHome;
private int gamesPlayedHome;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teamHome" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<MatchAnalyses> matchAnalysesHome;

public TeamHome() {
}
```

Match entity

```
@Entity
public class MatchAnalyses {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private TeamHome teamHome;

@ManyToOne(fetch =  FetchType.LAZY)
private  TeamAway teamAway;

public MatchAnalyses() {
}

private final double e = 2.718283;

private  double calcoloA = (((this.teamHome.getGoalsScoredHome()/this.teamHome.getGamesPlayedHome())+
        (this.teamAway.getGoalsConcededAway()/this.teamAway.getGamesPlayedAway()))/2.0) ;
private  double calcoloB = (((this.teamAway.getGoalsScoredAway()/this.teamAway.getGamesPlayedAway())+
        (this.teamHome.getGoalsConcededHome()/this.teamHome.getGamesPlayedHome()))/2.0);

private  double teamHomeEnd0 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloA, 0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloA)) / 1.0);
private  double teamHomeEnd1 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloA, 1.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloA)) / 1.0);
private  double teamHomeEnd2 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloA, 2.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloA)) / 2.0);
private  double teamHomeEnd3 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloA, 3.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloA)) / 6.0);
private  double teamHomeEnd4= (((Math.pow(this.calcoloA, 4.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloA)) / 24.0);
private  double teamHomeEnd5 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloA, 5.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloA)) / 120.0);
private  double teamHomeEnd6 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloA, 6.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloA)) / 720.0);

private  double teamAwayEnd0 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloB, 0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloB)) / 1.0);
private  double teamAwayEnd1 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloB, 1.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloB)) / 1.0);
private  double teamAwayEnd2 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloB, 2.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloB)) / 2.0);
private  double teamAwayEnd3 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloB, 3.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloB)) / 6.0);
private  double teamAwayEnd4 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloB, 4.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloB)) / 24.0);
private  double teamAwayEnd5 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloB, 5.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloB)) / 120.0);
private  double teamAwayEnd6 = (((Math.pow(this.calcoloB, 6.0)) *
        Math.pow(e, this.calcoloB)) / 720.0);

//Risultati partita "PAREGGIO"
private double teamH0_teamA0 = this.teamHomeEnd0 *
        this.teamAwayEnd0 * 100;
private double teamH1_teamA1 = this.teamHomeEnd1 *
        this.teamAwayEnd1 * 100;
private double teamH2_teamA2 = this.teamHomeEnd2 *
        this.teamAwayEnd2 * 100;
private double teamH3_teamA3 = this.teamHomeEnd3 *
        this.teamAwayEnd3 * 100;
private double teamH4_teamA4 = this.teamHomeEnd4 *
        this.teamAwayEnd4 * 100;
private double teamH5_teamA5 = this.teamHomeEnd5 *
        this.teamAwayEnd5 * 100;
private double teamH6_teamA6 = this.teamHomeEnd6 *
        this.teamAwayEnd6 * 100;
 public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public TeamHome getTeamHome() {
    return teamHome;
}

public void setTeamHome(TeamHome teamHome) {
    this.teamHome = teamHome;
}

public TeamAway getTeamAway() {
    return teamAway;
}

public void setTeamAway(TeamAway teamAway) {
    this.teamAway = teamAway;
}


public double getTeamH0_teamA0() {
    return teamH0_teamA0;
}

public void setTeamH0_teamA0(double teamH0_teamA0) {
    this.teamH0_teamA0 = teamH0_teamA0;
}

public double getTeamH1_teamA1() {
    return teamH1_teamA1;
}

public void setTeamH1_teamA1(double teamH1_teamA1) {
    this.teamH1_teamA1 = teamH1_teamA1;
}

public double getTeamH2_teamA2() {
    return teamH2_teamA2;
}

public void setTeamH2_teamA2(double teamH2_teamA2) {
    this.teamH2_teamA2 = teamH2_teamA2;
}

public double getTeamH3_teamA3() {
    return teamH3_teamA3;
}

public void setTeamH3_teamA3(double teamH3_teamA3) {
    this.teamH3_teamA3 = teamH3_teamA3;
}

public double getTeamH4_teamA4() {
    return teamH4_teamA4;
}

public void setTeamH4_teamA4(double teamH4_teamA4) {
    this.teamH4_teamA4 = teamH4_teamA4;
}

public double getTeamH5_teamA5() {
    return teamH5_teamA5;
}

public void setTeamH5_teamA5(double teamH5_teamA5) {
    this.teamH5_teamA5 = teamH5_teamA5;
}

public double getTeamH6_teamA6() {
    return teamH6_teamA6;
}

public void setTeamH6_teamA6(double teamH6_teamA6) {
    this.teamH6_teamA6 = teamH6_teamA6;
}
```

Match Repository

```
@Repository
public interface MatchAnalysesRepo extends 
JpaRepository<MatchAnalyses,Integer> {

public MatchAnalyses findMatchAnalysesById(Integer idMatchAnalyses);
}
```

Match Service

```
@Service
public class MatchService {

private MatchAnalysesRepo matchAnalysesRepo;

@Autowired
public MatchService(MatchAnalysesRepo matchAnalysesRepo) {
   this.matchAnalysesRepo = matchAnalysesRepo;
}

public MatchAnalyses newMatch(MatchAnalyses matchAnalyses)  {
   return matchAnalysesRepo.save(matchAnalyses);
}

public MatchAnalyses getMatch(Integer id) {
   return matchAnalysesRepo.findMatchAnalysesById(id);
}

public List<MatchAnalyses> allMatch() {
   List<MatchAnalyses> list = new ArrayList<>();
   matchAnalysesRepo.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(list::add);
   return list;
}
```

Match Controller

```
@Controller
public class MatchController {

private final MatchService matchService;
private final TeamHomeService teamHomeService;
private final TeamAwayService teamAwayService;

@Autowired
public MatchController(MatchService matchService,TeamHomeService teamHomeService,TeamAwayService teamAwayService) {
    this.matchService = matchService;
    this.teamAwayService = teamAwayService;
    this.teamHomeService = teamHomeService;
}


@GetMapping("/ris/{idMatch}")
public String getR(Model model,@PathVariable("idMatch") Integer idMatch) {
    MatchAnalyses match = matchService.getMatch(idMatch);
    model.addAttribute("H0risA0", match.getTeamH0_teamA0());
    model.addAttribute("H1risA1", match.getTeamH1_teamA1());
    model.addAttribute("H2risA2", match.getTeamH2_teamA2());
    model.addAttribute("H3risA3", match.getTeamH3_teamA3());
    model.addAttribute("H4risA4", match.getTeamH4_teamA4());
    model.addAttribute("H5risA5", match.getTeamH5_teamA5());
   return "rismatch";
}

@PostMapping("/newmatch")
public String addMatch(Model model,@ModelAttribute("teamHome")TeamHome teamHome,
                             @ModelAttribute("teamAway") TeamAway teamAway) {
    MatchAnalyses matchAnalyses = new MatchAnalyses();
    matchAnalyses.setTeamHome(teamHome);
    teamHome.getMatchAnalysesHome().add(matchAnalyses);
    matchAnalyses.setTeamAway(teamAway);
    teamAway.getMatchAnalysesAway().add(matchAnalyses);
    matchService.newMatch(matchAnalyses);
    return "redirect:/rismatch";
}

@GetMapping("/newmatchview")
public String addViewNewMatch(Model model) {
    MatchAnalyses matchAnalyses = new MatchAnalyses();
    model.addAttribute("match",matchAnalyses);
    model.addAttribute("teamHomeList", teamHomeService.allTeamHome());
    model.addAttribute("teamAwayList" , teamAwayService.allTeamAway());
    return "addmatch";
}

@GetMapping("/allmatch")
public String fullMatch(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listMatch" , matchService.allMatch());
    return "rismatch";
}
}
```

this is the error i get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QermH.png)

```
teamHome.getMatchAnalysesHome().add(matchAnalyses);
```

I cannot save the TeamHome and TeamAway entities in Match
My goal is to create a Match object with TeamHome and TeamAway fields (Handler "addMatch") and then recall the results of a match with getters (Handler "getR").Is the reasoning for reaching the goal correct?

thank you all for your time and help

Comment: For calculation you don't want to create third entity calculate in `Controller` and pass it to thymeleaf using `Model`

Comment: how can i pass these calculations and display them with thymeleaf?

Comment: Pass it using `Model` Or `ModelMap` Or `ModelAndView`. if you are not familiar with Model see here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view

Comment: I looked at the documentation and tried but doesn't work. Could you please give me a quick example? thanks for the time spent

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a team is an away team or a home team should be modeled in the `Match` class, you don't need `TeamAway` and `TeamHome` as separate classes.

I would advice to create 1 class `Team` like this:

```
@Enity
public class Team {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  private String name;
  private int goalsScored;
  private int goalsConceded;
  private int gamesPlayed;

  /* Getter and Setter omitted */

}
```

Next, you can create the `Match` entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Match {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Team teamHome;
  
  @ManyToOne
  private Team teamAway;

  /* Getter and Setter omitted */
}
```

I changed your `@OneToOne` to `@ManyToOne` as I assume a single team can play multiple matches.

The calculations can be left in the `Match` class, you just need to foresee getters so the controller can access the results.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MatchController {

  private final MatchService service;

  public MatchController(MatchService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public String index(Model model) {
    Match match = service.getMatch(...); //somehow get a `Match` instance from the Service.
    
    model.addAttribute("teamH0_teamA0", match.get....); // use the correct getter on the `match` instance

    // call `addAttribute` for each of the values you want to display on the Thymeleaf page

    return "match" // return the name of your Thymeleaf template. In this case, the template should be `src/main/resources/templates/match.html`
  }

}
```

In the Thymeleaf template, use the attributes:

```
<div th:text="${teamH0_teamA0}"></div>
```